# Some CasperJS functions not consistent

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have written some modules for CasperJS for my testing purposes. They consist of various functions that are used repeatedly. I have noticed that the same functions are not working for same functionality across different pages. When I investigated into it I discovered that actually native CasperJS functions are the ones causing troubles.

For example:

```
waitUntilVisible('.buy')
```

was working for me all of the time and lately when writing new piece of code it does not return true anymore. I have tried to replace it with

```
waitFor(function(){
    return this.exists('.buy');
}
```

and still no luck... After that I tried to use evaluate like this

```
waitFor(function(){
    return this.evaluate(function(){
        return $('.buy').length > 0;
    })
}
```

which normally asserts to true. As well seeing the screenshot before and after this snippet clearly shows that element is there.

The weird thing is that this exact snippet of code, which checks for buy button and clicks on it if it there, works on other pages which are identical.

Here is the one of the function that is not working

```
this.checkButton = function(){
    casper.waitUntilVisible('.buy',function(){
        this.test.pass('Button visible');
        this.click('.buy');
    },function(){
        this.test.fail('Button not visible');
    }).waitUntilVisible('div.header h2', function(){
        this.test.pass('Button works');
    },function(){
        this.test.fail('Button does not work');
    })
}
```

Listening to page.error and remote.message gave nothing.

My current wait timeout is set to 30 seconds.

Do anyone have any idea what could go wrong?

Thanks

edit:
So it looks like that problem is module related. I literally copied a code from various functions in module to 1 procedural file. And it works normally. The procedural code is below:

```
.then(function(){
    var records = casper.evaluate(function(){
        return document.querySelectorAll('.content table tr').length;
    });
    if(records > 0) this.test.pass(records +' records shown');
    else this.test.fail(records +' records shown');
})
.waitForSelector('#main .btn.small',function(){
    this.test.pass('Load more button found')
}, function(){
    this.test.fail('Load more button not found')
})
.then(function(){
    if(this.exists('#main .btn.small')) this.test.pass('Button exists');
    else this.test.fail('Button does not exist !?');
})
.thenClick('#main .btn.small')
.then(function(){
        this.sendKeys('.listfilter-wrapper input','2487');
})
.wait(5000)
.then(function(){
    var length = casper.evaluate(function(){
        return $('.content table tr').length;
    });
    if(length < 40) this.test.assert(true,'Search works, number of results for "2487": '+length);
    else this.test.assert(false, 'Search does not work');
})
```

And this is the same code written in module:

```
this.isLoaded = function(){
casper.then(function(){
    var records = casper.evaluate(function(){
        return document.querySelectorAll('.content table tr').length;
    });
    if(records > 0) this.test.pass(records +' records shown');
    else this.test.fail(records +' records shown');
});
},

this.loadMore = function(){
casper.then(function(){
    if(this.exists('#main .btn.small')) {
        this.test.pass('Load more button exists');
        casper.click('#main .btn.small');
        casper.wait(500);   
    }
    else this.test.fail('Load more button does not exist')
})
},

this.search = function(){
casper.then(function(){
    this.sendKeys('.listfilter-wrapper input','2487');
}).wait(5000);
casper.then(function(){
    var length = casper.evaluate(function(){
        return $('.content table tr').length;
    });
    if(length < 40) this.test.assert(true,'Search works, number of results for "2487": '+length);
    else this.test.assert(false, 'Search does not work');
});
}
```

This is the function that calls steps

```
module.exports = function(){
  this.check = function(){
      platform.navigateTo('Actions');
      this.isLoaded();
      this.loadMore();
      this.search();
  }
}
```

And this is the call of module

```
a = require('./modules/actions');
var actions = new a();
casper.test.begin('Testing',8,function suite(test){
casper.start();

actions.check();

casper.run(function(){
    test.done();
});
})
```

Comment: Hi Mario, can you provide information about used version of casperjs and if your configuration is exactly the same for different pages? Like using phantomjs for one page and slimerjs for another page? Did i anderstand right that you always got a fail / timeout for the test even if you´ve proofed with screenshots that the element was there? In which context is this.checkButton is running?

Comment: I haven't run into those kinds of issues. There is a PhantomJS bug when using `:nth-of-type()` and `:nth-child()` selectors, but it seems, you're not using them. Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors. If there are not, maybe you can provide a complete script that has this problem.

Comment: I'm only using phantomJS v1.9.8 and casperJS v1.1.0-beta3, so no slimerJS... 

 I have some errors regarding resources that are not loaded because of TLS I guess. The whole code is huge since I am testing whole platform that is written in knockoutJS. Are there any know issues? I've searched for a long time could not find any... Since this is huge part of code I will investigate it 1 function at a time and will write back results.

Comment: ok, I added some code, do you have any idea now? @ArtjomB.

Comment: Looks fine. How do you load the module and queue up the steps?

Comment: There, I added the code @ArtjomB.

Comment: Seems fine. Sorry, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after investigating more, I think this issue is related to phantomJS issue with consistency of css selectors with nth-of-type and calling the casper.reload(). By removing reload() function I eliminated most of failures in my test, there is still much more selectors that I need to replace to test if it is related to that.

Hope that helps.